# Explaining why factor analysis fails

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I am trying to perform factor analysis on a data set in R using the `factanal()` function, but I keep getting the error `unable to optimize from this starting value`. Therefore, I'd like to identify the features (columns) which are causing this situation, and explain why they're causing it. I think I've mostly succeeded at the former (see below), but am quite clueless at the latter, and would appreciate any help, as I'd like to have a principled explanation for why I need to omit the offending features from the analysis.

Both the data set and the R script can be easily cloned from this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/dlukes/mda) for experimentation. I include only snippets from the script below (the `dplyr` and `limma` libraries are used).

After loading the data into `res.data`, I found that these two calls fail:

```
fit <- factanal(res.data, factors=8, rotation="promax", trace=T)
# unable to optimize from this starting value
fit <- factanal(res.data, factors=7, rotation="promax", trace=T)
# unable to optimize from this starting value
```

So I set out to investigate what's causing this. I wrote a function `factanal_fail_feats()`, which repeatedly runs `factanal()` on the data while excluding a fixed proportion of randomly picked columns each time. It returns a sorted vector of counts of how many times a feature was present when `factanal()` failed:

```
# WARNING: Takes a while to complete! Interim results are reported periodically.
fail_feats <- factanal_fail_feats(res.data)
head(fail_feats)
#   NN  NOM   VF STA4  GEN CLUN
# 4459 4406 4190 4186 4088 4063
fit <- factanal(select(res.data, -NN), factors=8, rotation="promax", trace=T)
# unable to optimize from this starting value
fit <- factanal(select(res.data, -NN, -NOM), factors=8, rotation="promax", trace=T)
# unable to optimize from this starting value
fit <- factanal(select(res.data, -NN), factors=7, rotation="promax", trace=T)
# success!
```

This told me that the feature `NN` is problematic, but why? Is it perhaps because it's linearly dependent on other features?

```
is.fullrank(res.data)
# FALSE
is.fullrank(select(res.data, -NN))
# FALSE
```

Hmm, so the matrix does seem to contain linearly dependent columns, but removing `NN` doesn't help.

I then wrote a function `lin_dep_feats()` which is similar to `factanal_fail_feats()`, except it tests column-wise subsets of the data for being full rank (linearly independent). This identified two completely different columns as being problematic:

```
ld_feats <- lin_dep_feats(res.data)
head(ld_feats)
#   WL   TC NEG1 COH1  NNV VTE1
# 7505 7386 7065 7062 7057 7056
is.fullrank(select(res.data, -WL, -TC))
# TRUE
fit <- factanal(select(res.data, -WL, -TC), factors=8, rotation="promax", trace=T)
# unable to optimize from this starting value
fit <- factanal(select(res.data, -WL, -TC), factors=7, rotation="promax", trace=T)
# unable to optimize from this starting value
```

Removing these two newly identified columns alone didn't do anything useful w.r.t. `factanal()`, but if I remove the 4 features identified as "problematic" by both approaches, the `factanal()` call finally succeeds even with 8 factors:

```
fit <- factanal(select(res.data, -NN, -NOM, -WL, -TC), factors=8, rotation="promax", trace=T)
# success!
```

As a sanity check, randomly removing 4 features doesn't do anything helpful (whew):

```
fit <- factanal(res.data[, sample(1:ncol(res.data), ncol(res.data)-4)], factors=8, rotation="promax", trace=T)
# unable to optimize from this starting value
```

At this point, I decided to take a look at the correlations between the problematic features and the rest of the data set...

```
feat_cor <- function(data, feat_name) {
  cor <- cor(data[[feat_name]], data)
  sort(setNames(c(abs(cor)), colnames(cor)), decreasing=TRUE)
}

head(feat_cor(res.data, "NN"))
#        NN      CLUN        PP       GEN        WL        DB
# 1.0000000 0.9172335 0.9017139 0.8935881 0.8575989 0.8565588
head(feat_cor(res.data, "WL"))
#        WL      ATA1        AA       GEN      STA4        NN
# 1.0000000 0.9053217 0.8816113 0.8799450 0.8589837 0.8575989
head(feat_cor(res.data, "TC"))
#        TC       PPI       BIG       NNV       VVO      STA4
# 1.0000000 0.5262275 0.4937046 0.4823765 0.4687399 0.4630486
```

... but nothing really conspicuous came up, and I have to admit I am stumped. Is there an approach that would help me explain why the features I've identified are making `factanal()` fail, so that I can give a reasonable explanation for removing them from the analysis?